# How can I migrate data, adding a new column with constraints, with flashback archives enabled?

Tags: sql, oracle, flashback

I've currently got a string value in one table, which I would like to change so that it references another table. For instance, currently I have:

```
| Table: Animal       | 
-----------------------
| Name      | Class   |
|-----------|---------|
| Horse     | Mammal  |
| Crocodile | Reptile |
```

And I want these to reference my new "AnimalClass" table, so that they look like:

```
| Table: Animal       | 
-----------------------
| Name      | ClassId |
|-----------|---------|
| Horse     |    3    |
| Crocodile |    14   |
```

I've created my new table and set the ClassId without any trouble.

Unfortunately when I try to add a foreign key constraint between my new Id and the AnimalClass table, I get this error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-55610: Invalid DDL statement on history-tracked table
```

This makes sense, because it invalidates the "Undo".

Is there any way to migrate the historic data in line with my new data, so that I can add my constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Oracle are you using (client and server)?  According to this thread there are issues with using older clients: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=945177    If nothing else works, can you use DBMS_FLASHBACK_ARCHIVE.DISASSOCIATE_FBA/REASSOCIATE_FBA?  (As recommended by http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17125/adfns_flashback.htm#BJFFDCEH)

Comment: Will look into that and accept if it leads to a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Okay - it didn't lead to a solution, but it did lead to the recognition that the version we've got really doesn't work particularly well with DDL changes. Your suggestion would work fr the next version up. Getting a patch. Thank you!